# 3rd of 3 queries.add method fails with runtime error 5

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm adding 3 sets of queries to a workbook. The 1st and 2nd queries.add method works and functional queries are added, but the 3rd queries.add fails with a runtime error 5 message and no queries are added. The code is similar for all 3 procedures: query name and formula are retrieved from excel sheet cells.values. When I copy the M-code formula from the Excel Formula 'bar' and manually paste into the Power Query Editor, the query builds, functions properly and saves ok. Since all 3 routines retrieve their M-code the same way, it seems unlikely that corrupted M code is the problem (but I'll keep an open mind).

Anyone have a similar problem? I've tried everything that I can think of to find the problem, but I'm stumped.

Here is the code as one procedure. (I've broken it into 3 procedures to test it, but that has not made any difference).

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportTextFile()

    Dim connStr As String

    Dim queryName, queryFormula, queryDescription, dataConnSource, dataConnLocation, _
                commandText, listObjName As String
                
    Dim s, i, x As Integer
    
    ' XXXX   LISTS          :The first 9 queries get saved as Connections only                      +++++++++++++++++++  +++++++++++++++++++
    ' YYYY   Common Queries :The next 5 queries get saved as Connections to the data model only     +++++++++++++++++++  +++++++++++++++++++
    ' ZZZZ   Other Queries  :The next 20 queries get saved as Connections to QueryTables            +++++++++++++++++++  +++++++++++++++++++
        
'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    
    ' XXXX   LISTS          :The first 10 queries get saved as CONNECTIONS only

    For s = 3 To 12
    
        ' Get values for variables
        queryName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All_Code_Variables").Cells(s, "C").Value
        queryFormula = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All_Code_Variables").Cells(s, "D").Value
        queryDescription = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All_Code_Variables").Cells(s, "E").Value
    
        ' Add a New Query to the workbook Queries collection  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=queryName, Formula:=queryFormula, Description:=queryDescription

        'Add connection only ...no need to make a separate connection string and can be used WITHOUT a listObject QueryTable
        ' No need to add a sheet and no ListObject made
        ThisWorkbook.Connections.Add2 Name:="Query - " & queryName, _
                              Description:="Connection to the '" & queryName & "' query in the workbook.", _
                              ConnectionString:="OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & queryName & ";Extended Properties=""""", _
                              commandText:="SELECT * FROM [" & queryName & "]", _
                              lCmdtype:=2, _
                              CreateModelConnection:=False, _
                              ImportRelationships:=False
    Next

'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    
    ' YYYY   Common Queries :The next 5 queries get saved as Connections to the DATA_MODEL only

    For i = 13 To 16
    
        ' Get values for variables
            queryName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All_Code_Variables").Cells(i, "C").Value
            queryFormula = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All_Code_Variables").Cells(i, "D").Value
            queryDescription = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All_Code_Variables").Cells(i, "E").Value
    
        ' Add a New Query to the workbook Queries collection  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=queryName, Formula:=queryFormula, Description:=queryDescription
        
        'Add Data Model Connection to connections collection
        ThisWorkbook.Connections.Add2 Name:="Query - " & queryName, _
                            Description:="Connection to the '" & queryName & "' query in the workbook.", _
                            ConnectionString:="OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & queryName & ";Extended Properties=", _
                            commandText:="" & queryName & "", _
                            lCmdtype:=6, _
                            CreateModelConnection:=True, _
                            ImportRelationships:=True
    
    Next
    
 '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 
     ' ZZZZ   Other Queries  :The next 20 queries get saved as Connections to QUERYTABLE

     For x = 17 To 38
    
        ' Get values for variables
            queryName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All_Code_Variables").Cells(x, "C").Value
            queryFormula = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All_Code_Variables").Cells(x, "D").Value
            queryDescription = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All_Code_Variables").Cells(x, "E").Value
    
'Runtime Error 5 Here        ' Add a New Query to the workbook Queries collection  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=queryName, Formula:=queryFormula, Description:=queryDescription

        'Create the Connection string   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        connStr = "OLEDB;" & _
                  "Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;" & _
                  "Data Source=$Workbook$;" & _
                  "Location=" & queryName & ";" & _
                  "Extended Properties="""""

        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        
        'Add a Query Table to our Worksheet     +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        ' a connection string is added to the ListObject
        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _
                                         LinkSource:=True, _
                                         xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, _
                                         Source:=connStr, _
                                         Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
                                                                    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
                                                                    .commandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & queryName & "]")
                                                                    '.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                                                                    
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

........................................

Comment: What row does it throw the error on? Is it possible there's something wrong with the data or format of a random cell? When I've had issues with something working manually but not in VBA it was because VBA thought something was a Date when it wasn't

Comment: One possible cause for this error could be that a query with the same name already exists in the workbook's collection of queries, and the "Queries.Add" method is unable to add the new query with the same name. You can check for this by adding a check to see if a query with the same name already exists before adding the new query.

Comment: Another possible cause could be that the query formula or query name is invalid. You can check this by manually pasting the query formula into the Power Query Editor and seeing if it builds and functions properly.

Comment: It may also be a good idea to check the memory or the excel version you use. If you are running this code on an older version of excel, it might not be able to handle the complexity of the formula.

Lastly, I would recommend adding some error handling to your code to catch and handle any errors that may occur during the execution of the code. This will help you to identify the specific cause of the error, and make it easier to troubleshoot and fix the problem.

Comment: Thank You Maya and Zen. Memory is ok, version is Excel365,I'll add some error code,manual pasting of the formula works fine,i'll add some query name checker, the cells are all formatted as General--I changed them to text, but still fails on the FIRST try at adding queries by the last of the 3 queries.add.  One thing I failed to mention initially is that this query that fails has a  'Source = Table.NestedJoin' whereas all the prior formulas that are added by the first 2 queries.add do not contain any joins...any chance that could be the cause of a failed add?

Comment: Fails on the FIRST try at adding queries by the last of the 3 queries.add.(See above code comment: 'Runtime Error 5 here').

Comment: The problem was that I had a' Description' parameter for the 'queries.add' method, but I had an empty cell with nothing in it for a description and that is what caused the Runtime error 5. The solution was to either supply 'Description' with a string/variant or simply omit it from the queries.add method, either solution worked fine.